# Shopping Cart Price Promotion on total only

Tags: magento-1.9, promotions

I have set up Discounts on a couple of Products for a specific Customer.
While the discount is applied correctly, it is shown at the end of the Checkout page. I'd prefer the individual Product Discount to be shown on the product line.

Is this an option?

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Your need to study following topics before do this:

->catalog_rules

->conditions in rules

->special price on product

In last you want to show discounted amount on product page,then you call special_price on product-detail-page.